# document.getElementById("myId") vs component.find("myId").getElement();

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, id, aura-id

What is better to use `document.getElementById("myId")` or `component.find("myId").getElement();` in terms of performance? What will be faster?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regardless of performance, you should use `component.find`. Document query selectors aren't recommended in lightning, whereas `component.find` **[has explicit support](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_dom.htm)**:

> ### Valid DOM Access
>
> The following methods are valid DOM access because the elements are created by `c:domLocker`.
>
> ```
> cmp.getElements()
> ```
>
> Returns the elements in the DOM rendered by the component.
>
> ```
> cmp.find()
> ```
>
> Returns the div and button components, identified by their aura:id attributes.
>
> ```
> cmp.find("div1").getElement()
> ```
>
> Returns the DOM element for the div as c:domLocker created the div.
>
> ```
> event.getSource().get("v.name")
> ```
>
> Returns the name of the button that dispatched the event; in this case, myButton.

Notice the complete absence of query selectors in the enumeration of valid methods to access the DOM. It's not a supported approach, strictly speaking, even if it may work today.